How can I produce a multiplication table using org-tables?
I could produce a multiplication table by writing
| 3 |  9 | 15 | 21 |
| 5 | 15 | 25 | 35 |
| 7 | 21 | 35 | 49 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*3::$3=$1*5::$4=$1*7

but it would be a lot clearer if I started from
|   | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 |   |   |   |
| 5 |   |   |   |
| 7 |   |   |   |

and used a single expression.
How can I produce a multiplication table using org-tables?

Here's one way:
* Multiplication table

|   |  3 |  5 |  7 |
| 3 |  9 | 15 | 21 |
| 5 | 15 | 25 | 35 |
| 7 | 21 | 35 | 49 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2..@>$> = @0$1 * @1$0

The relevant section of the manual is References (which you can read in Emacs , using Info, with C-h i g(org) RET i references):@0, $0, @> and $> are explained in the Field references subsection; the .. notation on the LHS is explained in the Range references subsection.
